# findOneAndUpdate - return only pushed item in array back

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have problem with a mongodb query.

I update the array, it works. But it returnes the full document back, the array with all the items. I need to return the array with only the last item pushed.

Any idea how to do that?

Here is my code.

```
const updateMessage = (userId, messageId) => {
    return OperationMessageUser.findOneAndUpdate({
        userId: userId,
        'messages.messageId': {
            $ne: messageId
        },
    }, {
        $addToSet: {
            messages: {
                messageId: messageId,
                status: 1,
                lastRead: Date.now()
            },
        },
    }, {
        new: true,
        //projection: 'messages',
    });
};
```

Comment: why return it? why not memoize it?

Comment: then do `return OperationMessageUser.findOneAndUpdate(...).messages[0]`

Comment: I need to return it to the client-appliaciton.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const updateMessage = (userId, messageId) => {
    return OperationMessageUser.findOneAndUpdate({
        userId: userId,
        'messages.messageId': {
            $ne: messageId
        },
    }, {
        $addToSet: {
            messages: {
                messageId: messageId,
                status: 1,
                lastRead: Date.now()
            },
        },
    }, {
        new: true,
        //projection: 'messages',
    }).messages[0];
};
```